# JS - innerHTML changing to new element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reveal.js

I am making a slide with Reveal.js. I am using a js file to change the HTML elements:

```
document.getElementById("audio1").innerHTML = "<source data-src='../../learn/audio/lesson1/" + a_audio + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>";
```

But it is weird, because this is what is show in the console:

```
<source type="audio/mpeg" src="../../learn/audio/lesson1/dog.mp3">
```

Why is the *type* tag moved to the front, and why is *data-src* changed to *src*?

Note: If I hard-code the HTML element then it stays the same.

Comment: I've tried it out and it doesn't do anything what you mentioned.

Comment: Please tell us what browser is exhibiting this behavior

Answer (score 0):

In Reveal.js when you use lazy loading, the element is altered automatically when the slide gets in range. See this link for more details: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#lazy-loading